# Approval by Admin to confirm the change

Tags: php

I have a problem to solve, but I don't understand how I can.

---

User can edit a post, but Admin approval is required to confirm the change.

While waiting for Admin to confirm the modification of the new post, the old version of the post must remain available for all users.

Can you tell me if this is possible and how?

Thank you very much !!!

I hope I have explained myself correctly.

Comment: Sounds like you need users to be contributors so that when they save their post they're set to pending review, then an editor or higher level user can review and publish. You don't need code or a plugin to do this though

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work that way for me.
Even if I use (contributor) the changes are immediately reflected on the site without the need for any approval.